# How to add UITableviewController inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have one view controller which is a `subclass` of `UITableViewcontroller`, that `UITableViewcontroller` i need show under one `UIView` which I need to assign `Corner Radius` so it will match with my design.

UITableViewcontroller is the Generic `tableview` class which I have used in the whole project so I couldn't make changes in the structure.

**All my ViewController are created programmatically, i have not used anywhere Storyboard.**

> Here is my Viewconroller Code where I am implementing
>
> 1. headerViewController is part which i mark as white
> 2. deal and team controller is my UITableviewController which i have added in SJSegment

```
     private func setupSegmentController() {
        segmentViewController.headerViewHeight = 350
        segmentViewController.headerViewController = headerViewController

        segmentViewController.segmentControllers = [
            dealViewController,
            teamViewController]
        segmentViewController.delegate = self
        
        addChild(segmentViewController)
        segmentViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(segmentViewController.view)
        segmentViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
      }
```

Below in red highlighted is the area which i need to design

[image]

Comment: 1. Either add UItableview in the view and make use of its delegates and data sources, or 2. Use a container view and embed UITableviewController into it like a child view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370856/4549304 this may help you

Comment: My deals and teams controller already added as child views in SJSegmentedScrollView

Comment: Adding corner radius to the view suffices then, or i may not be able to understand your view hierarchy, can you elaborate other missing items.

Comment: You can't add view controller in UIVIew. Either you can add tableview in view or can add view controller's view into another view by adding view controller as child.

Comment: Updated Question with code snippet

Comment: @user1374, add the corner radius to view that has segmentViewController as child, that is all

Comment: You need to subclass UITableView and add UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate to your custom class.

Comment: i have also tried with that but it applied to the whole segmentViewController, as you can see in image i want only in deals and terms controller

Comment: @user1374 can you share the UI of the DESIGN you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you want to add a view controller as child in some other view controller. You have to use ContainerView in the View Controller where you want to show that table Table View Controller. Create an outlet of that Container View then add the table view as child.

```
let yourTableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourTableViewController") as! UITableViewcontroller
yourTableViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
yourTableViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
self.addChild(yourTableViewController)
containerView.addSubview(yourTableViewController.view)
yourTableViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Or he can just subclass UITableView. Creating A ViewController is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UITableView` and `view.addSubview(yourCustomClass)` . It is not necessary to add `UITableViewController` inside your UIView

Answer (score 0):

Controllers it's also a basic class that can control your view. You can add as subview tableView you your generic view and set their delegate and dataSource to the main view controller. You don't need to create tablewviewcontroller for this.

all you need is - (inside main view controller)

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self.
```

and after this you must implement protocol conformance

```
MainViewController: UITableViewCOntrollerDelegate {

// implementation here
}
```

```
MainViewController: UITableViewControllerDataSource {
// implementation here
}
```

After this you can customise your table view like view and do what you want